# Invalid Redeclaration of Variable in Swift Protocol Extension

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

In Swift, from what I understand, protocols describe attributes which can apply to a data structure. Protocol extensions then, allow for those attributes to be defined per data structure to which they apply.

If that is true, why does the following error appear:

> invalid redeclaration of 'invalid'

On this line:

```
extension CausesError where Self: Example { var invalid: Bool { return true } }
```

In this code:

```
struct Example: CausesError { }

protocol CausesError { var invalid: Bool { get } }

extension CausesError where Self: Example { var invalid: Bool { return true } }
```

Comment: Did you notice that there is another error? *"type 'Self' constrained to non-protocol type 'Example'"* – That is the real problem.

Comment: I don't see that error, only the one mentioned in the question, followed by the console noting the location of its initial usage. That said, Xcode doesn't always have consistent error presentation, so what would such an error indicate?

Comment: `Example` is a `struct`, a value type that does not allow inheritance. `Self` can neither conform to (as to a protocol) or inherit from (as for a class) `Example`. If you e.g. change `Example` to `class` instead of struct, the above will compile.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. How would you define a default extension for a struct though?

Comment: A struct is concrete type, so you defining a "default implementation" of `invalid` would simply corespond to conforming to the protocol. You could choose to let `Example` _conform_ to `CausesError` by extension rather than at declaration: `extension Example: CausesError { var invalid: Bool { return true } }`, but this is mostly semantics (w.r.t. direct conformance). This is not the same as supplying a _default_ implementation (for a group of objects e.g. derived from a class type or conforming to some protocol), however, but simply conformance by a specific type to a given protocol.

Comment: So then what is the purpose (intended use case) of `extension Example: CausesError` and `extension CausesError where` etc.? Why would someone use the second one?

Comment: The former is _conformance_ by a specific type to a given protocol, and has nothing to do with default implementions. The latter allows adding default implementations, _at a protocol level_, for groups of types that fulfil some requirements (e.g. upon `Self` or some associated type of the protocol). In the latter case, since we work at a protocol level, we need not know anything about the concrete types that _may_ conform to the protocol, we only supply default behavior that types _may_ have access to when conforming to the protocol, given that they fullfil the req. in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to synthesize what @dfri said for those who [see this later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) The actual error was caused by:

```
extension CausesError where Self: Example
```

Because Example is a struct, and therefore has no Self property.

The problem was that I had a fundamental misconception about protocol extension.

> A struct is concrete type, so defining a "default implementation" of invalid would simply corespond to conforming to the protocol. [One] could choose to let Example conform to CausesError by extension rather than at declaration:

```
extension Example: CausesError { var invalid: Bool { return true } }
```

> but this is mostly semantics (w.r.t. direct conformance). This is not the same as supplying a default implementation (for a group of objects e.g. derived from a class type or conforming to some protocol), however, but simply conformance by a specific type to a given protocol.

Therefore, what I should have done (in order to provide default implementation at a protocol level, even to data types) was simply:

```
extension CausesError { var invalid: Bool { return false } }
```